# How can I access the elements of a foreign set for a model in Django's get_context_data method?

Tags: python, django, generics, view, model

I have a generic `DetailView` in Django 1.9.7, which uses my model `Quiz` to show a super-time-saving no-hassle view (thank you Django). However, I'm struggling to access a related foreign key set on my `Quiz` object (a set of `QuizQuestion` objects). My model is as follows:

```
class QuizQuestion(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_index = models.IntegerField()
    user_answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date_answered = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    user_is_correct = models.NullBooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_answer_text
```

Here's my view:

```
class QuizDetail(generic.DetailView):
model = Quiz

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(QuizDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # Pass/fail chart
    passed_questions = self.model.quizquestion_set.objects.filter(user_is_correct=True)

    # ...

    return context
```

This gives me **'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'objects'**.

I'm not sure if trying to get the related objects using the `_set` is preferable to scooting around the long way and asking for `QuizQuestion.objects.filter(...)`, but I'm operating on the basis that it is. Please correct me if I'm mistaken :)

`self.model.quizquestion_set.filter(user_is_correct=True)` gives: **''ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter''**

`passed_questions = self.model.quizquestion_set.all()` gives **'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'**

*P.S. I find it quite obvious that I am relatively new to Django - apologies for any silly mistakes.*

Comment: please also add your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the *model*, you need to refer to the *instance* (the object for which the view is showing the details) as relations are for instances and not models. You can get the instance with `self.get_object()`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(QuizDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    obj = self.get_object()
    passed_questions = obj.quizquestion_set.filter(...)
    return context
```